# Accessing view that rendered the template from the template in django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I was wondering if it is possible to determine which view rendered a specific template in Django (or get a boolean result). For example:

```
{% if this_view %}
  some code
{% else %}
  some other code
{% endif %}
```

I'm probably way off but I was wondering how we could create similar conditional statement within the template. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can pass the name of the view as parameter. But this looks like bad design. In that case it might be better to make two templates that `{% incude ... %}` common parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the django's `request.get_full_path` to get the current url in the template and from the url you should be able to figure out the view.

You can also use [`request.resolver_match.view_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) in your template to get the view name

Comment: That's not the *view*, but the *path*. Multiple *paths* can lead to the *same* view. Resolving paths in a template is quite bad design.